# Composed distribution relation

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Given independent random variables $A, B$ and $C$, for which we know $x = P(A > B)$ and $y = P(B > C)$; how, if possible, can we derive $z = P(A > C)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can't. Even though $A>B$ and $B>C$ can guarantee $A>C$, there is no clear relationship the other way around.

We can only say here $z\geq xy$.